# Making a local struct instance accessible to another function (C++)

Tags: c++, scope, game-development

So I have a struct which holds variables for entities within a game (hit points, x and y coordinates, etc) and I have the struct declared globally. However, I have the instances created in a "setup" function and want their variables to be modified in a separate "logic" function. But obviously, since the instances are local to the "setup" function, the "logic" function can't modify their variables.

This is a simplification of my current code.

```
// Global space
struct entity {
     int hp, atk, x, y;
};

void Setup()
{
    entity dummy;
    dummy.hp = 10;
    dummy.atk = 2;
    dummy.x = 5;
    dummy.y = 5;
}
void Logic()
{
    // if(dummy is attacked)
        dummy.hp -= 4;
}
int main()
{
    Setup();
    while(game is not over)
        Logic();
}
```

Comment: research function return values

Comment: Also functions can have parameters.  You can have `logic` take a `enity` so it can use it in the function.

Comment: @NathanOliver What if I made a function that takes `entity` but is called within `logic`? The reason being that `logic` handles movement and attacking (both player's and enemy's) as well as pathfinding. I think it may be best to wrap each of these into their own functions and call them all under `logic`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways you can solve this:

1. move `dummy` into global scope:

```cpp
struct entity {
    int hp, atk, x, y;
};
entity dummy;

void Setup()
{
    dummy.hp = 10;
    dummy.atk = 2;
    dummy.x = 5;
    dummy.y = 5;
}

void Logic()
{
    if (dummy is attacked)
        dummy.hp -= 4;
}

int main()
{
    Setup();
    while (game is not over)
        Logic();
}
```

2. Move `dummy` into `main()`, and then pass it by reference (or pointer) to `Setup()` and `Logic()`:

```cpp
struct entity {
    int hp, atk, x, y;
};

void Setup(entity &e)
{
    e.hp = 10;
    e.atk = 2;
    e.x = 5;
    e.y = 5;
}

void Logic(entity &e)
{
    if (e is attacked)
        e.hp -= 4;
}

int main()
{
    entity dummy;
    Setup(dummy);
    while (game is not over)
        Logic(dummy);
}
```

3. an extension of #2 above, you could then move `Setup()` and `Logic()` into the struct itself:

```cpp
struct entity {
    int hp, atk, x, y;
    void Setup();
    void Logic();
};

void entity::Setup()
{
    hp = 10;
    atk = 2;
    x = 5;
    y = 5;
}

void entity::Logic()
{
    if (is attacked)
        hp -= 4;
}

int main()
{
    entity dummy;
    dummy.Setup();
    while (game is not over)
        dummy.Logic();
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. I should have probably clarified that the purpose of making a struct was to add as many different instances of entities as needed in runtime. I don't believe the second nor last solution would work in this case, but I don't know about the first one either, since it isn't in a function for me to control it in.

Comment: #2 and #3 would work just fine with multiple `entity` objects. You can then use an array or vector or list or whatever you want to keep track of the objects at runtime, calling `Setup()` and `Logic()` on each object as needed.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I'll try #2 along with separating `logic` into different specialized functions (not shown in the question). Thanks a lot!